# R function: For-loop creating "NA" value instead of integer

Tags: r, function, for-loop

the function below works when I use 1, or start with 1 for place.  If I use another number (e.g. 2 or 3:5, etc) I get the following error `cannot open file 'foo\NA.csv': No such file or directory.` This has been modified from a homework question I am working on. I don't know why this value of "NA" is being created. All files are named number (e.g. 001, 010, 100) .csv

```
fix1 <- function(dir, place = 1:10) {
  nrows <- vector()
  for (i in place){
      id <- formatC(as.integer(place), 2, flag=0)
      in_file <-paste(dir,"\\", id[i], ".csv",sep="")
      in_data <- read.csv(in_file, header=T, sep=",")
      nrows <- c(nrows, (nrow(in_data)))
      }
return(df1 <- data.frame(place,nrows))  
return(df1)

  }
```

Comment: You're using `i` to both represent the actual elements in `place` as well as a counter to indicate where in the vector `place` you are. You can't do both. Think about what `id[i]` would return the first time through your loop if `place = 2`.

Comment: 'id <- formatC(as.integer(i), 2, flag=0)`
'in_file <-paste(dir,"\\", id, ".csv",sep="")`  , thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
fix1 <- function(dir, place = 1:10) {
    nrows <- integer(length(place))  # agstudy's suggestion; more efficient
    for (i in seq_along(place)){
        id <- formatC(as.integer(place[i]), 2, flag=0)
        in_file <- paste(dir, "\\", id, ".csv",sep="")
        in_data <- read.csv(in_file, header=T, sep=",")
        nrows[i] <- nrow(in_data)
    }
    data.frame(place=place,nrows=nrows)
}
```